# VueJS - Got JSON and want to create a table to count distinct values

Tags: json, html-table, vue.js

Got following .json:

```
[{
"STATUS": "0500",
"POSID": "..."
},
{
"STATUS": "1500",
"POSID": "..."
},
{
"STATUS": "0500",
"POSID": "..."
}]
```

I want to create a table in vue-js with 2 columns.
First column shows STATUS and second column counts number of .json elements with that status.

Output should be like that, in a table:

```
Status    Count 
0500      2 
1500      1
```

Currently I'm just writing the full table with v-for:

```
<tr v-for="data in data">
  <td>{{ data.Status }}</td>
</tr>
```

Tried it with filter but I won't accomplish it.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it now with:

```
  <tr v-for="(value, key) in countData">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
     </tr>
```

and

```
  countData (jitcalls) {
    return _.countBy(_.map(this.jitcalls, function (d) {
      return d.ANLIE
    }))
```

Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

This logic can be implemented directly by javascript. Vue.js is not and should not be responsible for this.
You can use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) from lodash or write your own implementaion.

This is one of possible solutions:

```
computed: {
   preparedData(){
      return _.groupBy(this.data, 'STATUS');
   }
}
```

And then use `preparedData` instead of `data` in the template.

```
<tr v-for="(value, key) in preparedData">
  <td>{{ key }}</td>
  <td>{{ value.length }}</td>
</tr>
```

Check the example here: https://codepen.io/probil/pen/MOVMQj?editors=1010

Comment: Won't work, maybe I'm implementing it wrong.
How can i generate a table with 2 colums, one with the different values from "STATUS" and one with the count?

Comment: @sleepysimon Updated!